# Backward Slash & Piping Operator key not working in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have the laptop : HP 15-da1041TU

I tried changing the keyboard layout of my laptop a couple of times, but it won't work.
(Generic-101 does not work)

The key is not being registered (But it works on Windows - dual boot)
I'm not even getting its keycode on my laptop to set it via **xev**

Is there a way to manually link the key to its character? (Not getting any search results for it)

---

`localectl status` ouput is

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_IN
                  LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc102
```

It used to also work when I had Ubuntu 19.10 (I had reasons to revert back).
I guess the keypress is detected, because whenever I press it, the terminal cursor stops blinking

Comment: Welcome! Could you explain what did you do to change it?

Comment: Also, could you post the output of the command `localectl status`? [edit] the question, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I had a HP 15 inch Core2Duo machine and backslash key didn't work at all, another reviewer of HP 15 pavilion i3 user have a same problem. Thus that is at least 10-year tradition of HP, phoned HP support center. They can't do anything about it. I assigned another key to type \ and |.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka but OP says that it works in windows.

Comment: @guillemo chamorro, yes then they found the way to solve it on Windows. My case was; the laptop came with a Japanese keyboard and I replaced with US layout and replace Windows HDD with Ubuntu SSD, so mechanically backslash key works and I don't know where it is connected.

Comment: @karel I cannot remap the key as it's keycode is not known to me... Is there any **graphical** tool to set the {key: character} relation?

Comment: `xev -event keyboard` on the command line can tell you the keycode and the character that the locale (XLookupString) gives.  Look for "KeyPress" and "KeyRelease" events.

Comment: @ThomasWard `xev` doesn't detect those keypresses as a character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was definitely a config file in **/home** which was causing this problem. I reinstalled the OS formatting my **/** but the problem persisted ... I deleted all config files in **/home**, but quite a few were auto-generated back again.

So I formatted also my **/home** also while reinstalling the OS, and the problem was solved!

Comment: maybe "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration"
could have helped?

Comment: @MaxRobbertze Thanks for the info! I'll look into it. But I cannot say if it would work, because that unresponsive state is long lost.